# Extracting data in twilio studio liquid template

Tags: templates, twilio, liquid

I am trying to get the phone number in studio  liquid-template.No matter what pattern I turn into it never extract the data.considering the data is a return object from a http post

> {{widgets.http_1.parsed.attributes.phone}}

> {{widgets.http_1.parsed["attributes"].phone}}

> {{widgets.http_1.parsed.[attributes].phone }}

> {{widgets.http_1.body["attributes"].phone }}

> {{widgets.http_1.body.attributes.phone}}

> {{widgets.http_1.parsed["attributes"].phone}}

```
{accountSid=ac, activityName=Offline, activitySid=wa, 
      attributes={
        "onlyOutboundCallMode": false,
        "routing": {
            "skills": [
               "english"
            ]
        },
        "email": "@gmail.com",
        "phone":"12323"
    }, 
    available=false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deeply nested objects, you will need to parse the data outside Studio. Take a look at the Studio execution logs of your Studio flow. See if the HTTP Request widget was able to parse the JSON structure.

Returning this structure worked for Studio which parsed it:

```
let respObj = {
    accountSid: "ac", 
    activityName: "Offline",
    activitySid: "wa", 
    attributes: {
      onlyOutboundCallMode: false,
      routing: {
        skills: [
        "english"
        ]
        },
        email: "@gmail.com",
        phone:"12323"
    }, 
    available: false}
```

Result in Studio:

```
"parsed": {
        "accountSid": "ac",
        "activityName": "Offline",
        "activitySid": "wa",
        "attributes": {
          "onlyOutboundCallMode": false,
          "routing": {
            "skills": [
              "english"
            ]
          },
          "email": "@gmail.com",
          "phone": "12323"
        },
        "available": false
      }
```